# Can't connect to server with SSH, Showing " ssh: connect to host 178.128.60.26 port 22: Connection timed out" in Windows 10

Tags: windows, git, ssh, server, port

When I am trying to connect to a server via ssh it is throwing an error "ssh: connect to host 178.128.60.26 port 22: Connection timed out". My operating system is windows 10. And I am using Git bash for connecting via ssh. Checked the blocked ports in the firewall. Port number 22 is open for all networks. I already connected to the server via ssh but now I can't.

[image: Firewall open ports]

Answer (score 1):

Check first if you can ping the server.

But if you do:

- either the server itself is not running the ssh daemon service (but then the error woudl more likely be "`connection refused`")
- or it is, but on a non-conventional port (your ssh call would need to be `ssh -p <another_port> ...`) (again, the error would more likely be "`connection refused`")
- or its firewall rules prevents any incoming ssh request: that would actually generate a time out.
  If the remote machine is a Linux one: `sudo service ufw status` (assuming you have access to said server, or you can ask an administrator to check)

Comment: Checked the firewall rule but it is fine. And tried with different port but no luck

Comment: @VishnuSasidharan I meant check the ssh status and firewall rules on the remote server you are trying to connect to.